# What is the number ways to map alphabet to alphabet without overlap?

Tags: encryption

I want to make mapping table with alphabet to alphabet. We can't use same alphabet value and key.

For example, we can use key A - value C , key B - key D. But we can't use key A - value A, key C - value C. In this situation, what is the number of mapping tables that we can make?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the number of mapping tables (of a substitution cipher). Do you want to exclude all Caesar cipher type substitutions or just the identity mapping?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a generic question about encryption better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com. I'd factor out 1 from 26 by the way :P Your English is excellent, it's more a problem that your question doesn't contain a *programming* language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

148,362,637,348,470,135,821,287,825.

> In combinatorial mathematics, a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is a permutation of the elements of a set, such that no element appears in its original position. In other words, derangement is a permutation that has no fixed points.
>   -Wikipedia

Assuming you're only using 26 substitutions (e.g. capital letters), the question boils down to "what's the number of derangements for a set of 26 items?"; which is `1.48e26`, which is about a 63% reduction in the total keyspace (26! == `4.03e26`).

For large values it turns out to be approximately equal to `n! / e` (e being the number approximately equal to 2.71828).